# Bathroom Shelving with Sliding Mirrors - Best method and weight limit?

Tags: bathroom, shelving, support

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cDb6.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeOcO.jpg

[image: drawing of bathroom shelving]

I'm wondering what might be the best method of installing 71" wide by 7.25" deep wood shelving that will be supporting 3 sliding mirrors (about 8 pounds each) via an embedded track, along with some other bathroom supplies / cleaning products (I'm not sure of total weight).

I added linked images showing what the studs looked like when the bathroom was being re-finished and we considered creating a recessed cabinet (the wall is now closed, but I can access it all via a 2nd bathroom behind this wall, which I'll have re-modeled in the future).

Originally I was contemplating floating shelving that would slide onto metal rods drilled into the studs (.5" x 10" bolts, rebar, pre-made brackets, or something similar). I could drill a hole from the opposite side of the back wall, through some of the studs to be used as a support rods.

I could just use 3 wood pieces screwed into the studs (1 at back and 1 per side wall), while the shelf sits on top of them. 
Or use a combo of these methods - since I'd think there needs to be some additional depth support in the center of the 71" wide shelving. I'd prefer not to use L brackets that would be visible under the shelving.

I would paint the wood white, or stain it.
Since it is in a bathroom (has a fan and window, but can get humid), is there a specific wood or other material that I should be considering? I was going to use 2x8s

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I had a design similar  to what you are doing, sliding glass doors across 120".  but found this using Ikea cabinets, comes in various width.  The style I used has mirrow on the inside back, back of tdoors as well.  Opening a door puts a mirror inches away from you.  With these you don't have to be concerned about safety code for mirror used in the bathroom.  Some have lights built on the top surface, some with strip ligts on the inside edge, etc.  Here is a link to one just with [Mirron on outside door] (https://www.ikea.com/us/en/p/lillangen-mirror-cabinet-with-2-doors-white-20205171/)

Comment: The link above is to cabinets with just mirrows on the outside of the doors.  This [link](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/p/godmorgon-mirror-cabinet-with-2-doors-10218999/) is to cabinets with mirrows on every surface, top, bottom, inside, edges, etc.